# Nothing is saved in Account settings

Tags: 8

When I'm at this page "admin/config/people/accounts" I can't change anything of the settings. So I uncheck a checkbox or typ another value in an input. When I click the save button, the page reloads but the settings go back to the values before.

Anyone who knows the problem? Other pages does save my settings, it only appears on the "admin/config/people/accounts".

I use Drupal 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any modules that could break this ? What is your exact Drupal 8 version ? You can test the same behaviour with the exact same version on simplytestme and see what's happening. If it works, so you can look into your contrib/custom modules.

Comment: a) check your admin theme if its printing the form_build_id, form_token and form_id as hidden fields, usually at the end of the form. If not, you have malforormed form template. b) see if there isn't some field without title. If so and this field is getting form error, the lack of title will result in no error message being shown and element not highlighted so you do not know what is going on(basically form is not being submitted).

Answer (score -1):

In modules check for the `hook_user_admin_settings_alter`, check the form action and change it for the modules implementing those function

`$form['#submit'][] = 'module_user_admin_settings_submit';`

For reference sample forgot_username module

Instead of this 
`$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'forgot_username_user_admin_settings_submit';`,

use this
`$form['#submit'][] = 'forgot_username_user_admin_settings_submit';`

In my case, forgot_username module breaks the account savings.

Reference : https://www.drupal.org/project/private_message/issues/2905184
Patch : https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/private_message-admin_settings_submit_handler_beta18-2905184-3.patch